# Getting a contact's mail on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have an application with kind-of "share" function. How can I list the contacts stored on the iPhone to the user?

Can I do it without exiting my own app (required)?

Can I have the contacts content without opening any external view?

I assume it is somewhat secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NavigationController called ABPeoplePickerNavigationController that you can use in your app to select contacts or contact info.  This may get you down the right path.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbookui/abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller

Class description:
The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class (whose instances are known as people-picker navigation controllers) implements a view controller that manages a set of views that allow the user to select a contact or one of its contact-information items from an address book.